# scale WebView to fit screen on Android

Tags: android, html, webview

I ve got an app with uses HTML help files , one file for each Activity.

the WebView appears on top of Activity with semi transparency.

I have some problems trying to make the html content fit the screen of different devices

In my HTML file I have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And I add my HelpView to the current View via addContentView (with layout params MATCH_PARENT , MATCH_PARENT)

of some devices, it ok but not of some others.

I also try to override the onDraw method to scale the drawing matrix but I get some unexcpected results.

Any suggestions to fit my html as full screen on all devices (I dont mind if it s a bit stretched )

Comment: can you explain more what is not ok about it on the devices you are having trouble with? Screenshots would probably make this a lot easier for us to help you with too.